# Why does compiler assert that the returned slice immutably borrow from s?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

```
fn first_word(s: &str) -> &str {
    "there"
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello world");
    let word = first_word(&s);
    s.clear();
    println!("the first word is: {}", word);
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `s` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
7 |     let word = first_word(&s);
  |                           -- immutable borrow occurs here
8 |     s.clear();
  |     ^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
9 |     println!("the first word is: {}", word);
  |                                       ---- immutable borrow later used here
```

I'm learning rust and this is a demo from the rust book which I changed a little bit.  https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch04-03-slices.html

I'm confused about the error message at the bottom line where it says *word* immutably borrows from *s* while logically this hasn't to be the case. Does the compiler always assume that the returned slice must point to the sole argument somehow? Does this have anything to do with lifetime? What is the general reasoning rule here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning a string literal, `&'static str`. But the compiler never looks at function bodies while type checking - it only looks at their signatures.

`first_word()`'s signature is `fn first_word(s: &str) -> &str`, which by the [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html) rules is the same as `fn first_word<'a>(s: &'a str) -> &'a str`. So the compiler assumes the returned string borrows from the parameter string. It works because `&'static str`, which is actually returned, can be shortened to any other lifetime.

If you will declare `first_word()` as `fn first_word(s: &str) -> &'static str` then it'll work.

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed clever. I believe the lifetime specifier means that the compiler must check that the returned slice cannot out live its argument. Is it because the lifetime of *s* is considered to have ended before the last print statement?  If not, why this inevitably leads to the borrow relationship i still cannot see clearly. However a slice must borrow from something and there is really not much option. If it does not borrow from the argument if must either borrow from something owned by the function which is not allowed, or borrow from a string literal like in this demo.

Comment: @user1206899 The lifetime of `s` is not ended until the end of the scope, but the lifetime of its borrow ends earlier because we borrow `s` mutably and mutable and shared references cannot coexist.